# QuickSort infinite loop if I declare param defaults inside function using pre-2015 method, but works fine if I use ES2015 default param values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, parameters, quicksort, default-parameters

I have been trying to implement a quickSort function and have everything working. But there is one peculiarity that I cannot wrap my head around or understand why.

In this first block of code, you will see that I have declared some default param values for the `quickSort()` function:

```
function swap(arr, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
  let temp = arr[firstIndex];
  arr[firstIndex] = arr[secondIndex];
  arr[secondIndex] = temp;
}

function pivot(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
  // We are assuming that the pivot is always the first element
  let pivot = arr[start];
  let swapIndex = start;

  for (let i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
    if (pivot > arr[i]) {
      swapIndex++;
      swap(arr, swapIndex, i);
    }
  }

  // Swap the starting element with the pivot index
  swap(arr, start, swapIndex);
  return swapIndex;
}

function quickSort(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length - 1) {
  if (left < right) {
    let pivotIndex = pivot(arr, left, right);
    // left
    quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
    // right
    quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

In this example, it works fine as expected. However, if I were to remove the ES2015 default param values from `quickSort()` and, instead, create the defaults inside of the function, like this:

```
function quickSort(arr, left, right) {
  left = left || 0;
  right = right || arr.length -1;
  if (left < right) {
    let pivotIndex = pivot(arr, left, right);
    // left
    quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
    // right
    quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I get an infinite loop/Stack Overflow issue and I cannot understand why. From what I can tell, the issue is caused by the third param - `right` - rather than the left param, as the code works fine if I call the left param using the pre-es2015 method, whilst leaving the `right` param with the ES2015 param default method.

All in all, I have my code working, so that's fine - I just want to try and better understand why this would cause an issue, as I've never encountered such a problem before.

Thanks!

Comment: if you pass `0` to the third parameter, it gets changed to `arr.length - 1` in the second version - not so in the first version. The default value is use when no argument is passed - your code uses a default when the argument is anything falsey (like 0) ... to write the same code as ES2015, you need to check the length of the arguments, not the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your two versions work differently when `0` is passed as `right`. (And because that's a base case, you get an infinite loop).

```
right = right || arr.length -1;
```

evaluates to the right hand side when `0` is passed in, as `0` is falsy.

The default parameter initialiser on the other hand puts `0` in `right` if `0` is passed in, and evaluates the `arr.length - 1` expression *only* when `undefined` (or no argument at all) is passed in.

To replicate that behaviour, in ES5 you'd write

```
function quickSort(arr, left, right) {
  if (left === undefined) left = 0;
  if (right === undefined) right = arr.length - 1;
  if (left < right) {
    let pivotIndex = pivot(arr, left, right);
    // left
    quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
    // right
    quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Just tested the code with your changes and it works perfectly - thank you for the education good sir!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const quicksort = ([x, ...rest]) => (!x || x === undefined) ? [] : quicksort(rest.filter(a => a < x))
.concat(x)
.concat(quicksort(rest.filter(a => a >= x)))`
```

Sorry this is `ecmascript6` and not `es5`.